# Extracting sentences with Spacy POS/DEP : actor and action

Tags: python-3.x, spacy-3

Thank you for your assistance. I am using spacy to parse though documents to find instances of certain words and extract the sentence in a new df[column].
Here are some texts:

```
text = 'Many people like Germany. It is a great country. Germany exports lots of technology. France is also a great country. France exports wine. Europeans like to travel. They spend lot of time of beaches. Spain is one of their travel locations. Spain appreciates tourists. Spain's economy is strengthened by tourism. Spain has asked and Germany is working to assist with the travel of tourists to Spanish beaches. Spain also like to import French wine. France would like to sell more wine to Spain.'
```

My code works like this:

```
def sent_matcher(text: str) -> list:
    doc = nlp(text)
    sent_list = []
    phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
    phrases = ['Germany', 'France']
    patterns = nlp(data) for data in phrases]
    phrase_matcher.add('EU entity', None, * patterns)

    for sent in doc.sents:
        for match_id, start, end in phrase_matcher(nlp(sent.text)):
            if nlp.vocab.strings[match_id] in ['EU entity']:
                sent_list.append(sent)
    text = (sent_list)
    return text
```

This code works fine and pulls all the sentences that include the EU entity.

However, I wanted to take this to the next level and pull out sentences where the EU entity is the actor and identify what type of action they were taking. I tried using POS/Dependency to pull out Proper nouns combined with the verb but the nsubj was not always correct or the nsubj was linked to another word in a compound noun structure. I tried extracting instances where the country was the first actor (if token == 'x') but I always threw a string error even if I tokenized the word. I also tried using noun_chunks but then I couldn't isolate the instance of the country or tie that chunk back to the verb.

I am pretty new to NLP so any thoughts would be greatly appreciated on how to code this and reap the desired output.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like if you use [`merge_entities`](https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_entities) and follow the [rule-based matching guide for the DependencyMatcher](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#dependencymatcher) you should be able to do this pretty easily. It won't be perfect but you should be able to match many instances.